# Function to print a string from match in R

Tags: string, r

I currently have two tables that contain name data, and I'm using `%in%` to create a new binary variable if a name of one of the two lists appers in the second on too:

```
publications$IsTrainee = 1*(publications$AuthorLast %in% trainees$TraineeLast)
```

I would also like to create a new variable that prints the string(name) appearing in both lists, but I have trouble in finding a function that allows it. I looked in the `stringr` package, but perhaps I missed something. Thanks a million!

Trainees table:

```
 TraineeNumber Program          LastName EntryDate
    1               1     K12               LEE      2007
    2               2     K12               PAN      2007
    3               3     K12            SHAIKH      2007
    4               4     K12        MINZENBERG      2007
    5               5     K12            BREMER      2008
    6               6     K12         UNDERWOOD      2008
    7               7     K12         AVDALOVIC      2008
```

Publications table:

```
PubNum Publication_Year  AuthorLast CoauthorLast1 CoauthorLast2 CoauthorLast3
1      1             2007     ANUURAD            LU         RUBIN       PEARSON
2      2             2006       BARRY     LOCKRIDGE       SALAMAT       TINLING
3      3             2006      CARTER                                          
4      4             2006      CARTER           HAN       ABRESCH        JENSEN
5      5             2006        CHUI         ZAROW          MACK         ELLIS
6      6             2007 CRITCHFIELD    LEMONGELLO        WALKER        GARCIA
```

publications$IsTrainee:

```
  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [41] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [81] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Desired Output:

```
PubNum Publication_Year  AuthorLast CoauthorLast1 CoauthorLast2 Trainee  TraineeName
1      1             2007     ANUURAD            LU         RUBIN       0   NA
2      2             2006       BARRY     LOCKRIDGE       SALAMAT       1   BARRY
3      3             2006      CARTER                                   1   CARTER    
4      4             2006      CARTER           HAN       ABRESCH       1   CARTER 
5      5             2006        CHUI         ZAROW          MACK       0   NA
6      6             2007 CRITCHFIELD    LEMONGELLO        WALKER       1   WALKER
```

Comment: Please provide a data sample of publications and trainees and the desired output

Comment: assign the above line into a variable, lets say `x` and please provide the output, or simply provide `publications$IsTrainee`?

Comment: I've added the sample data of publications and trainees.  The desired output would be the publications table + a new variable (column) with the trainee's name, if relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking simply for something along the lines of

```
names <- c("albert", "john", "louise")
set <- c("louise", "james", "john")
names[names %in% set]
```

or are you asking for something else?

Edit in response to comment:

What about `ifelse(names %in% set, names, NA)`?

Comment: That's really close.  I've added more detail to the question above, including the tables I'm working with.  Thanks!

Comment: Super close: now how to get the results to write to the original csv file similar to: `Publications$TraineePub = 1*(Publications$AuthorLast %in% Trainees$LastName)` and `write.csv(Publications,file='ResultsPublicationsTrainee.csv')` @Adrian

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question...  are you asking how to create a new data frame column, and how to write data frames to csv?  If so you've already answered it yourself:  do something like `Publications$MyNewVariable <- ifelse(Publications$Names %in% some.set, Publications$Names, NA)` and then call `write.csv`.